# Player - Getting Current Time of the Video

Tags: swift, video, avfoundation, avplayer

I am using [Player](https://github.com/piemonte/Player) library in order to achieve full-screen video play. I believe it's using `AVFoundation` behind the scenes.

I can use `Float(self.player.maximumDuration)` to achieve full duration of the video. However, how can I access/manipulate currentTime of the video? (I don't know if it matters but the video is streamed from server.)

**Update:**

I tried `let currentTime = Float(self.player.currentTime().value)` but I receive:

> Value of type 'Player' has no member 'currentTime'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It´s as simple as this:

```
let currentTime = Float(self.player.currentTime().value)
```

Regards!

Comment: I tried this too, but unfortunately, it gives Value of type 'Player' has no member 'currentTime'. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: @senty, I´d need to see more code. To know where does the error come from.

Comment: This is the Player instance which I create at the top of my viewDidLoad as `var player = Player()` : https://github.com/piemonte/Player/blob/master/Sources/Player.swift . I am basically tweaking the demo code.

Comment: @senty, I see no errors with it. Just to debug, can you use a non-streamed video(one you have on the iPhone for instance) and check if it works in that way. If it doesn´t. You may have to print the stack to the NSLog before accessing the currentTime

Comment: there isn't a problem with your code not to work. The code doesn't work because Player class doesn't have anything called `currentTime()`. Thus xCode doesn't let me build the project - built failed

Comment: @senty. It´s strange, I tried on xCode with AVFoundation and player.currentTime, it worked

Comment: Did you download this [ https://github.com/piemonte/Player ], run Project>Player.xcodeproj and tried calling `print(player.currentTime)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98934/discussion-between-senty-and-ctabuyo).

Answer (score 0):

Try this **SWIFT 3 CODE**:

```
var player =  AVPlayerViewController()
let currentTime = Float((self.player.player?.currentTime().value)!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Swift 4 code:

```
let player =  AVPlayerViewController()
let currentTime = Float((player.player?.currentItem?.currentTime().value)!)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this :- 
let v = Float(self.player.currentTime().value)
let t = Float(self.player.currentTime().timescale)
let currentSeconds = v / t
print(currentSeconds)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.